# Кириллица в nano из git для Windows

Tags: windows, git, кодировка

Использую nano из пакета git, который находится в папке `usr\bin\` (https://git-scm.com/download/win). Но кирилица крокозяблами отображается. Как это исправить?

[image]

```
    # locale
    LANG=
    LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"
    LC_NUMERIC="C.UTF-8"
    LC_TIME="C.UTF-8"
    LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
    LC_MONETARY="C.UTF-8"
    LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
    LC_ALL=
```

Comment: попробуйте `en_US.UTF-8`

Comment: я прописываю `set LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8` и тогда работает. Но после того как закрываю консоль и запускаю по новой, все опять. Переменная не сохраняется.

Comment: @ESkri Это где мне прописать?

Comment: в WSL можно прописать в `~/.bashrc`: `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` , а где это в гите под винду - хз

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался. Нужно просто создать переменную среды LANG и туда запихнуть нужное значение. Просто если делать через set, то при закрытии консоли переменная не сохраняется.